# Overriding default toJS function in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I know that toJSON can be overridden as [described here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html), but is it possible to provide a custom toJS function?

Comment: Why do you want to override it? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Let me know if my answered work for you. If so please mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's as easy as writing a new function.

However, a better option would be to use the white-list argument inside of `ko.toJSON`.

`ko.ToJSON(vm, white-list, spacing)`.

**HTML**

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, replacer, 2)"></pre>
```

**JS**

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   var self = this;

   self.name = ko.observable();
   self.age = ko.observable();
   self.canEatLotsOfPizza = ko.observable();
   self.sawTheNewStarTrekMovie = ko.observable();
   self.watchesWheelOfFortune  = ko.observable();

   self.replacer = function(key, value) {
      if(!key) {
         delete value.canEatLotsOfPizza;
         delete value.sawTheNewStarTrekMovie; 
         delete value.watchesWheelOfFortune ; 
      }

      return value;
   };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```